# Drawing lines with opacity on a canvas with the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

There's a question very similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412881/drawing-overlapping-semi-transparent-lines-without-visible-overlap?lq=1).
The reason I'm posting this is because half the question in the link was never answered. I'm at the point where the line is consistent all the way through, but you can't see what you're doing while drawing. The code went something like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}, false);

var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
};
```

This worked, except that I'm unable to see what I'm drawing. I've seen some people talking about using a temporary canvas to draw visibly on, then copy the strokes to the main canvas, but I haven't seen an example that actually worked.

Comment: If you use kinetics js it will become little bit simple.

Comment: @SeeTheC Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be sure to look into that.

Comment: Here's a working example of drawing using a temp canvas overlaying a final display canvas.  When the user starts dragging the offscreen  canvas is moved onscreen (directly on top of the display canvas).  The current line is drawn on the temp canvas until the user stops dragging.  Then that line is drawn on the final display canvas and the temp canvas is moved back offscreen. http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sS3eR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code with kinetic.js :

Html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"  height="300px" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:3px solid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

cn.js :

```
$(function()
{

    var lineSx,lineSy,lineFx,lineFy;
    var ismouseDown=false;
    var line;
    var layerList=new Array();


    setInterval(function(){// for clearing the temp layer 

        var l=null,topLayer;
        var i=1;
        l=layerList.pop();      
        while(l){
            //console.log(l);
            if(i!=1){
                l.destroy();
                l=null; 
            }
            else{
                topLayer=l;
            }           
            l=layerList.pop();
            i++;
        }
        layerList.push(topLayer);

    },2);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        fill: 'black',        
      });    
    rect.on("mousedown",function(e){

        console.log(e);
        ismouseDown=true;
        lineSx=e.clientX;   
        lineSy=e.clientY;   
    });
    rect.on("mousemove",function(e){

        if(ismouseDown){

            console.log(e);
            var cx=e.clientX;   
            var cy=e.clientY;

            var tempLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            //stage.remove(tempLayer);
            line=createLine(lineSx,lineSy,cx,cy);
            tempLayer.add(line);
            stage.add(tempLayer);       
            layerList.push(tempLayer);                      
        }

    });
    rect.on("mouseup",function(e){
        ismouseDown=false;
        console.log(e);
        lineFx=e.clientX;   
        lineFy=e.clientY;

        line=createLine(lineSx,lineSy,lineFx,lineFy);
        layer.add(line);
         stage.add(layer);  
    });

    layer.add(rect);    
    stage.add(layer);


});
function createLine(sx,sy,fx,fy){
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [sx,sy,fx,fy],
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
     });
     return line;

}
```

Comment: I have put the code in jsfiddle. Link :  http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/B4F6n/3/

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'll mess around with this for a while and see if any other answers show up.