# HTML5 Canvas transparency for all overlapping content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made an Drawing App with HTML5, it's just a basic paint/brush tool that currently works good. the problem is, i don't know how to make overlapping path have the same opacity.

i tried to use `globalAlpha` property but the overlap content is get bolder and bolder everytime i draw the line.

```
ctx.beginPath(); // init at onmousedown
ctx.lineTo(x, y); // at onmousemove
ctx.stroke(); // at onmousemove
```

Comment: What code are you using to draw the line?

Comment: i use `lineTo` and `stroke`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412881/drawing-overlapping-semi-transparent-lines-without-visible-overlap Basically you want to end the stroke only once you've setup all the paths, not after every single path.

Comment: i have tried that solution, but it's different situation

Comment: this is my app http://comicedu.com/htmlcropper/v1 please try to upload your image then select brush tool, and start painting on your image

Comment: I see opacity on the left part (with red brush), and not on the right part (it's like the brush was a square instead of a circle). Which one looks bad to you? For what I see I'd say the left part is okay and the right part isn't. (Testing with Chrome here).

Comment: right part is not the problem, if you notice when you start drag your mouse the brush is a bit transparent, then it goes bolder (opacity = 1) when you keep dragging your mouse. that's the problem, did you notice it?

Comment: OK that's what I see. I'll write a detailed description in an answer (too long for a "comment").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: OK I got it all wrong. Basically all you need is to redraw your canvas "background" before you draw your lines.

It looks like you have this: http://jsfiddle.net/4naMG/2/

And I think you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/4naMG/1/

The only difference is that in the second case I redraw the background. Since I don't do anything special I just clear the canvas:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

Edit: same example with mouse button management and multi-path: http://jsfiddle.net/4naMG/3/

(nb: I cheated in the case of single-point paths for the sake of clarity).

Comment: wowwww...that's great! you're absolutelly a genius!! thanks man, you saved from my headache..thank a lot