# HTML Canvas: Changing color of transparent brush causes all colors on canvas to change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I pulled some inspiration from [this code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247356/html5-canvas-transparency-for-all-overlapping-content) as I'm trying to accomplish something very similar but with an additional layer that allows you to choose which color you'd like to mark up the canvas with. For whatever reason, everything works as expected, but when I select a new color and paint again (ie. `onMouseMove`), the colors of *all* of the lines I've previously painted have changed. Most stackoverflow answers say that I need to `ctx.beginPath();` and/or `ctx.close, but I've tried that in just about every variety you can think of. I'm using React here and have included all of my class methods below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    // Here we set up the properties of the canvas element.
    const { drawType } = this.props;
    const myCan = document.getElementById('myCan');
    this.canvas.width = myCan.width;
    this.canvas.height = myCan.height;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 12;
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = .5;
  }

  onMouseDown(e) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    const { drawType } = this.props;
    this.isPainting = true;
    const path = [];
    path.push(this.getCoord(e));
    this.line.push(path);
  }

  onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.isPainting) return;
    this.line[this.line.length - 1].push(this.getCoord(e));
    this.redraw();
  }

  getCoord(e) {
    const { drawType } = this.props;
    const x = e.nativeEvent.offsetX;
    const y = e.nativeEvent.offsetY;
    return [x, y];
  }

  redraw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    const { drawType } = this.props;
    // Change color of stroke based on prop passed down from parent
    if (drawType == null) { return; }
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = drawType === 'red' ? this.red : null;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = drawType === 'blue' ? this.blue : null;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.line.length; ++i) {
      const path = this.line[i];
      if (path.length === 0) continue;
      if (path.length === 1) {
        this.ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
        this.ctx.lineTo(path[0][0] + 1, path[0][1] + 1);
      } else {
        this.ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
        for (let j = 1; j < path.length; ++j) this.ctx.lineTo(path[j][0], path[j][1]);
      }
    }
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }


  endPaintEvent() {
    if (this.isPainting) {
      this.isPainting = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When the mouse moves, you clear and redraw. Okay, fine. I can't see where you're storing the colour of each point. Without doing that, selecting the right colours during the redraw process seems unlikely to be possible. ;)

Comment: Ha- apologies, I attempted to alias my colors and ended up missing a spot. I'm changing colors via the `this.ctx.strokeStyle` ternaries in my redraw() function.

Comment: I know, but that wont do it. You need to set the colour each time it changes. The redraw function clears the screen before redrawing the lines. The canvas doesn't know what colour they were. When the mouse moves, you need to store the coordinate *AND* the colour selected at that point in space and time. You need to set the colour before each line segment and stroke each segment individually. As I said - if you don't keep track of the colour of each pixel, you wont be able to reproduce the image after its cleared. Put another way - you need to keep track - the canvas doesn't...

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. So is there a way to pass the color to the canvas when the mouse moves? I currently set that color via a class-based parent component that changes the state of `drawType` when a button is clicked in the canvas wrapper and pass that `drawType` down to the child (what I have posted above) as a prop. Apologies if the answer is obvious, I'm very new to the canvas element.

Comment: Well, why not store the position as returned by getCoord *and* the currently selected colour? Something like `curData = {pos: getCoord(), colour: curValueOfAGlobal}; followed by `this.line[this.line.length - 1].push(curData);`

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. So I've gone ahead and implemented this but still see all colors change when I start to paint a new line. Where should I define my `ctx.strokeStyle` and pass it that color global?