# FabricJS - Canvas blend mode in free drawing mode

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, blending

When using fabrics free drawing mode I want to add different lines to the canvas with an opacity. These lines should not add up their opacity when drawn on each other. Therefore I'm changing the canvas blend mode to `xor`. Anyway, when drawing lines over each other the opacity still adds up. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a", {
  isDrawingMode : true
});

document.getElementById("cbFreeDrawing").onchange = function () {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = this.checked;
};

canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 25;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "rgba(255,0,0,.5)";
//this seems not to work
canvas.getContext().globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
Drawing Mode: <input id="cbFreeDrawing" type="checkbox" checked="true"/><br/>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412881/drawing-overlapping-semi-transparent-lines-without-visible-overlap

Comment: Just visit this page: http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the freeDrawing you are drawing on the `upperCanvasEl`, a canvas element placed over the `lowerCanvasEl`.
The contexts for those elements are always ready to get in the properties:
`canvas.contextTop` and `canvas.contextContainer`.

What you can do is to set the single path globalCompositeOperation to 'xor' when it gets passed to lowerCanvas. There is an event (path:created) that you can use.
I moved the background in a separate canvas ( but it can be just an image placed down the canvas ) so that the lines does not xor with background itself.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a", {
  isDrawingMode : true
});
var canvas2 = new fabric.StaticCanvas("b");
canvas.lowerCanvasEl.parentNode.appendChild(canvas2.lowerCanvasEl)

document.getElementById("cbFreeDrawing").onchange = function () {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = this.checked;
};
canvas.on('path:created', function(opt) {
  opt.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
  canvas.renderAll();
});
canvas2.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png', canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 25;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "rgba(255,0,0,.5)";
//this seems not to work
canvas.contextTop.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
Drawing Mode: <input id="cbFreeDrawing" type="checkbox" checked="true"/><br/>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="b" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Andrea. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm not able to see any difference in the result compared to my example above. Am I missing something?

Comment: no, sorry, i misunderstood the question. Different lines drawed in different moments. let me check

Comment: changed the answer. i did not understand properly the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to not add up opacity _while_ drawing over existing paths? I guess the problem here are the different canvas layer so `globalCompositeOperation` wont work.

Answer (score 0):

+AndreaBogazzi just found out the answer provided only works when opacity is .5 if its set to another value opacities are overlapped / combined / behave in another way.

Fiddle (simplified for better understanding): https://jsfiddle.net/c8mf391q/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a", {
        isDrawingMode : true
});



canvas.on('path:created', function(opt) {
  opt.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
  canvas.renderAll();
});


canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 25;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "rgba(255,0,0,.3)";
```